# how I can access to my child routes via localhost?

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

Hi I can't access the child routes I mean when I type

`localhost:4200/general-managment/list-site`

this doesn't go to list-site HTML.

this is my list.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-list',
  templateUrl: './list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./list.component.scss']
})
export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
 showlist = true;
   constructor(private router: Router,
          private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   }
  siteList() {
    this.router.navigate(['list-site'] , {relativeTo: this.route});
    this.showlist = false;
 }

}
```

in `this.router.navigate(['list-site'] , {relativeTo: this.route});` i try `/list-site` and `./list-site` and `../list-site` but it doesn't work

this is my app-routing.service.ts:

```
 import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
 import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
 import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
 import { LogoutComponent } from './header/logout/logout.component';
 import {GeneralManagementComponent} from 
        './home/generalmanagement/generalmanagement.component';
 import {SiteComponent} from './home/general- 
      management/list/site/site.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'log-out', component: LogoutComponent},
  {path: 'general-management' , component: GeneralManagementComponent , 
      children : [
      {path: 'list-site' , component: SiteComponent}
           ]}
   ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
})

export class AppRoutingService {
}
```

and this is my HTML file :

```
  <button> id="close-image" type="button" class="box" (click)="siteList()"> 
   <img class="list-content" src="assets/imgs/download.jpg">Site
   </button>
```

I using angular 6.
how I can fix it

I use console here:

```
siteList() {
    console.log(this.router.navigate(['list-site']));
    this.router.navigate(['list-site'] , {relativeTo: this.route});
    this.showlist = false;
  }
```

and this is what i see :

```
__proto__:
catch: ƒ (onRejected)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: zone.js:966
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]
finally: ƒ (onFinally)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: zone.js:969
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]
then: ƒ (onFulfilled, onRejected)
arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 2
name: ""
prototype: {constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: zone.js:955
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]
constructor: ƒ ZoneAwarePromise()
all: ƒ (values)
race: ƒ (values)
reject: ƒ (error)
resolve: ƒ (value)
toString: ƒ ()
__zone_symbol__uncaughtPromiseErrors: []
 arguments: (...)
caller: (...)
length: 1
name: "ZoneAwarePromise"
prototype: {then: ƒ, catch: ƒ, finally: ƒ, constructor: ƒ}
__proto__: ƒ ()
[[FunctionLocation]]: zone.js:883
[[Scopes]]: Scopes[4]
 __proto__:
constructor: ƒ Object()
hasOwnProperty: ƒ hasOwnProperty()
isPrototypeOf: ƒ isPrototypeOf()
propertyIsEnumerable: ƒ propertyIsEnumerable()
toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()
toString: ƒ ()
 valueOf: ƒ valueOf()
__defineGetter__: ƒ __defineGetter__()
__defineSetter__: ƒ __defineSetter__()
__lookupGetter__: ƒ __lookupGetter__()
__lookupSetter__: ƒ __lookupSetter__()
get __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
set __proto__: ƒ __proto__()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just need create new div and in the new div i call **router-outlet** and its work well :)

Answer (score 0):

Because when you call `list-site` route it tries to generate a `SiteComponent` but your component is called `ListComponent`.

So here is how your `app-routing.service.ts` should look like:

```
 import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
 import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
 import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
 import { LogoutComponent } from './header/logout/logout.component';
 import {GeneralManagementComponent} from 
        './home/generalmanagement/generalmanagement.component';
 import {ListComponent} from './home/general- 
      management/list/site/site.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'log-out', component: LogoutComponent},
  {path: 'general-management' , component: GeneralManagementComponent , 
      children : [
      {path: 'list-site' , component: ListComponent}
           ]}
   ];
```

Comment: no, that path is correct but  when I try to search `localhost:4200/general-management/list-site it doesn't work also when I press the button it works well but I can't get access with URL And I know that I called it badly

Comment: Ok then when you say "it doesn't work", what do you mean ? What does your `SiteComponent` look like ?

Comment: this is my menu: https://prnt.sc/le7zvx   and when I press **Site** it is like this https://prnt.sc/le80ag

Comment: and this is my list-site html:    <button style="font-size: 15px">i am list-site</button>

Comment: Ok but when you click the button, what's the error in console ? @tondar

Comment: After this, I will add the question to my question